# Is it possible to launch vim from a capistrano task?

Tags: capistrano

I want to use capistrano for a custom sets of tasks on a remote server not directly related to deployment, it would be useful for me if I can start vim using capistrano, I've tried with this:

```
set :pty, true
execute "vim #{shared_path}/my_file.txt"
```

But I receive this (for obvious reasons)

```
  01 stdin: is not a tty
  01 Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
  01 Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

It's there anyway to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't start vim without a terminal. You could start a terminal with vim in it, here are a few ways to do this:

Start a terminal like st, xterm or similar. Examples:

```
x-terminal-emulator -e vim 

st -e vim

xterm -e vim
```

This solution is not the best, as terminal-emulators can have different switches for executing commands on call. **-e** is working for st and xterm.

A better solution is to start a shell like zsh, bash or similar, because almost every shell works with the same switch, which is **-c** to start a program directly in it. Example:

```
zsh -c vim

bash -c vim
```